# Find equation based on conditions

Tags: functions

I need to find an equation $p(x)$ based on these conditions:

- $\lim_{x\to-\infty}p(x)=4$
- Point discontinuity at $x=0$
- Non-removable discontinuity at $x=-\frac32$

I think there is an asymptote at $p(x)=4$ but I still don't know how that is represented in an equation or any of the other conditions for that matter. The equation is all I need. If anyone could give it to me that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 4 + 1/x + 1/(x+3/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the non-removable discontinuity at $x=-\frac32$ we need a rational function whose denominator is zero at that point. The simplest such function is
$$\frac1{2x+3}$$
We can create a point (or removable) discontinuity at $x=0$ by multiplying both halves of the fraction by $x$, which otherwise doesn't change anything:
$$\frac x{x(2x+3)}$$
Finally, note that this function has a horizontal asymptote of $y=0$. To turn this asymptote into $y=4$ it suffices to add 4 to the function, which gives us the final answer:
$$p(x)=\frac x{x(2x+3)}+4$$